# XSLT for converting empty body to a SUCCESS message

Tags: xslt, is-empty

I am trying to replace an empty response body, which is getting generated by a successful `DELETE` operation with a `"Success"` message via XSLT.

Can anyone help me with the XSLT which can simply print a `SUCCESS` message, if the response body is empty.

Response Body will be:
`<response status="204"> </response>`

Expected output:
`<response status="204">SUCCESS</response>`

Update from comment: If the response is **not empty** then it should print the same what comes back as a response.

Currently using the below XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it gives:
`<response/>`
as output.

Comment: Could you provide the sample XML and the desired output XML? If you have tried anything yet, please provide the XSLT as well.

Comment: The XML will be empty, so there will be no payload at all. 
The output should look like:
<Output>Success</Output>

Comment: Empty XML is not valid XML - how are you thinking of applying the XSLT to the XML?

Comment: Indeed! The response looks like this.
`<response status="204">
</response>`

And the output will be:
`<response status="204">
Success
</response>`

Comment: @Sammy And if the response is not empty?

Comment: P.S. Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add all these clarifications to it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k If the response is not empty then it should print the same what comes back as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone help me with the XSLT which can simply print a SUCCESS
>   message, if the response body is empty.
>
> If the response is not empty then it should print the same what comes
>   back as a response.

Then try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/response[not(node())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>SUCCESS</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome!! @michael.hor257k